# Creating C++ Blocking Function for Existing Asynchronous code

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I have a C++ plugin I have written for a proprietary software which makes an asynchronous call to a function called OpenLibrary.  To know when the library load has completed, I must register for a specific event.  Then, when that event is triggered, an OnEvent routine is called.  This logic is somewhat sterilized for proprietary reasons, but the asynchronous call and onEvent trigger works correctly.  Unfortunately, since the OpenLibrary call is asynchronous, the loop is not blocked and continues without waiting for the EVENT_LIBRARY_LOADED event.  I need to process the files serially.

```
...

void MyApp::main() 
{
    for(int i=0; i<total; ++i) {
        pData->RegisterEvent( EVENT_LIBRARY_LOADED, this );   
        pData->OpenLibrary("c:/path/file.dat");  // asynchronous call
    }
}

...


void MyApp::OnEvent( ID eventType ) 
{
    if (eventType == EVENT_LIBRARY_LOADED) {
        qDebug() << "Library load has completed";
    }
}

...
```

The plugin requires VS2008 and also takes advantage of the Qt library.

I would like to create a function called waitForEvent, where subsequent code is blocked until the event has occurred then waitForEvent can return control back to the calling routines loop.  This way, I can stay inside my main routines loop and simply wait for the event before continuing.  Any suggestions appreciated.

UPDATE: I have tried both excellent suggestions below by Tas, but in either case, I get the same result.  The WaitForSingleObject OR the condition_variable.wait BOTH prevent the EVENT_LIBRARY_LOADED event from triggering the OnEvent function from being called, which freezes the loop.

Any more suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Use a mutex and a condition variable?

Comment: It's my understanding that a condition variable is only available in vc++11?  I have made many various attempts along these lines, but due to inexperience, I have gotten no where.

Comment: @panofish if you really have to stick to older versions of c++, use the [boost library](http://www.boost.org/) - it provides mutex and condition variables. Alternatively you can implement the [Peterson algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm) or any other [mutual exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If boost libraries are an option, use `boost::condition_variable`

You've already made it clear C++11 isn't an option (otherwise you could use `std::condition_variable`). `boost::condition_variable` will accomplish what you need to do, and it's very simple to use. You only need to call `wait` and `notify_one`:

```
void MyApp::main() 
{
    for(int i=0; i<total; ++i) {
        pData->RegisterEvent( EVENT_LIBRARY_LOADED, this );   
        pData->OpenLibrary("c:/path/file.dat");  // asynchronous call
        condition_variable.wait(); // wait until we've been signaled
    }
}

void MyApp::OnEvent( ID eventType ) 
{
    if (eventType == EVENT_LIBRARY_LOADED) {
        qDebug() << "Library load has completed";
        // signal completion:
        condition_variable.notify_one();
    }
}
```

## Otherwise you could use [Windows Event objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915(v=vs.85).aspx)

These work very similar to the above but are a little more complicated to use (and also OS specific).

```
HANDLE hEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
void MyApp::main() 
{
    for(int i=0; i<total; ++i) {
        // Prepare signal (otherwise if the signal has been Set already, Wait will return instantly)
        ::ResetEvent(hEvent);
        pData->RegisterEvent( EVENT_LIBRARY_LOADED, this );   
        pData->OpenLibrary("c:/path/file.dat");  // asynchronous call
        // wait for event to signal:
        ::WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
    }
}
    
void MyApp::OnEvent( ID eventType ) 
{
    if (eventType == EVENT_LIBRARY_LOADED) {
        qDebug() << "Library load has completed";
        // Signal event:
        ::SetEvent(hEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising... give me some time to absorb and implement... I will respond sometime tomorrow.  Thanks. :)

Comment: I implemented the Windows Event objects solution, but a strange thing is happening.  The WaitForSingleObject call is blocking the OnEvent from being triggered, so the loop is permanently stuck at WaitForSingleObject!?  Without the WaitForSingleObject, the OnEvent does get triggered.

Comment: I also tried the first suggestion with boost::conditional_variable and I got the same results as "Windows Event objects".  The conditional_variable.wait() command is blocking the EVENT_LIBRARY_LOADED and the OnEvent function never gets called... so the program loop freezes!?  Any more ideas much appreciated.

Comment: I must've assumed `OnEvent` was being processed on a thread of sorts. If it's being processed on the same thread it will make things more difficult (and none of the options above will help, sorry). You will basically need to block code, but continue to process the code that handles your `OnEvent`. Ultimately I'd recommend just putting your `pData` calls on another thread. `boost::thread` and `boost::mutex` will help you accomplish that